# Java regex expressions for floating point numbers separated by semicolons

Tags: java, regex

I have created an application that does some calculation, it is pretty simple.
The user has to enter an unknown amount of floating point numbers between 1 and 6 separated by semicolons, the decimal point can either be a "," or a ".".
Example:

> 2,3;2.4;3;5.4;3.3;5,5;6

So how would I ask for a case like that in regex, because right now I am using a work-around and that pretty much sucks because it is unnecessary code.

Comment: Why use a regex? Wouldn't it be simpler just to do `numbers.split(";")`?

Comment: thats kind of what i am doing, but i have to check for some cases like if there are double ";" (";;") or ",;" or ".;" or if it simply ends with ";" or whatever the user could do wrong :)

Comment: @dquijada split uses a regex ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use something like so: `\d+([,.]\d+)?(;|$)` (example [here](https://regex101.com/r/eB8aQ8/1)).

This will attempt to match a number, which is optionally followed by a decimal section (denoted by the `.` or `,` characters). After each number, it expects to find a semi colon or the end of the string.

EDIT: As per your last comment: `((([0-5]([,.]\d+)?)|(6([,.]0*)?))(;|$))+` would do what you are after. An example is available [here](https://regex101.com/r/eB8aQ8/2).

Comment: So i have tried that

but for example when i type in 2;4 it says that it doesn't match

Comment: @ScriptKiddy: Please update your question with the code you are using. The expression I provided should match individual terms, not the entire line, so you would need to apply it multilpe times or else use something such as `(\d+([,.]\d+)?(;|$))+`.

Comment: that is already better thanks, i only need the number range to be between 1 and 6 do u also know how to do that, sry for that i am asking of so much withotu thinking myself.

Comment: @ScriptKiddy: See my update.

Comment: floating point numbers with "." don't work now :)

Comment: @ScriptKiddy: Please provide an example or two of whatever it is that is failing. I have tested it on the site provided and it is working for me.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109409/discussion-between-scriptkiddy-and-npinti).

Answer (score 1):

You could use this regex. What it does is checking if the number is in the range of `1-5`, followed by a floating point section, or just straight up the numbers `1-6`.

```
String input = "2,3;2.4;3;5.4;3.3;5,5;6";
System.out.println(input.matches("([0-5][,.]+\\d+(;|$)|[1-6](;|$))+\\d$);
```

Comment: Almost works perfect, i can still do things like that "4,;4" or "2;2;4;"

Comment: @ScriptKiddy The first one shouln´t be valid anymore after my latest edit. Might i ask why the second one isn´t correct, because you have non floating point numbers in the example aswell.

Comment: The second one has a semicolon at the end, it doesn't really matter cause it would still work after splitting the string into numbers but it doesn't look too well i think

Comment: @ScriptKiddy okay, changed it so the `String` has to end with a number.

Comment: now i can't enter a single number like "2" or "4,5"

Comment: @ScriptKiddy tested it, and single numbers aswell as chainged once should work.